# `less`: multiple commands, including a search

Tags: less, valgrind

Imagine you would want `less` to auto scroll to the end. Easy, as its manual states, do `less +G`.

Imagine you would want `less` to start at the beginning but after soaking its whole input. Easy, do `less +Gg` (to the end then back to the beginning), it supports several command chaining. Don't you believe? Chain `Gg` sequences enough, and you will end up watching `less` go back and forth.

Imagine you would want `less` to advance to the sixth occurrence of the `==` sequence. Can't use `less +/==nnnnn`! That searches `==nnnnn`, instead of searching `==` and then searching next five times. What to do now?

Comment: Use cat or grep?

Comment: Grep then More is a reasonable alternative, as it is just hitting the N key five times. However [multiple separate commands](https://superuser.com/a/1466515/174140) just working is perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you could, in fact, specify multiple separate commands like this:

```
less +/== +nnnnn
```

If that hadn't worked, you could embed a literal newline in the parameter:

```
less $'+/==\nnnnnn'
```

```
less "+/==
nnnnn"
```

Comment: All of those totally make sense. I don't know why, I can't run any of the three in my Konsole unless inside a nested Tmux organizer, nor in `tty1` to `tty6` unless inside a nested Tmux organizer. This is Debian GNU/Linux stretch 9.9 in `lsb_release -a`.

Comment: Compare `type less` and `printenv LESS` in both.

Comment: `less is /usr/bin/less` in all three of: `tty1` to `tty6`, inside Tmux, and in Konsole; in all three cases `printenv LESS` does not show anything, returning an exit status code of 1.

Answer (score 0):

This method uses `awk` to find the line number of the string and uses it as
parameter to `less`:

```
less +$(awk '/==/{++n; if (n==6) { print NR; exit}}' file) file
```

This was inspired by the Stack Overflow post
[shell script to find the nth occurrence of a string and print the line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162782/shell-script-to-find-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-string-and-print-the-line-number),
where are found more methods for finding the line number.

For ease of use, this command can be embedded in a bash function with the
file, string and occurrence number as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

#### In brief

For this purpose I did a function

```
Myless(){ less +g$(grep -n -m$2 "$1" "$3"  | cut -f1 -d: | tail -n 1) "$3"; }
```

then I call as

```
Myless == 6 myfile
```

---

Asking to `grep` to find the pattern, print the linenumber, `-n`, stop after the m-th occurence `-m$2`, cutting  the number `cut -f` d:`, taking the last one` tail -n 1`...

It can be optimized (for very large files) searching for the byte as a binary data and then pointing `less` to that byte...

... or it can be used `sed` in a more compact way to extract the linenumber (`sed -n '/pattern/=' myfile`)...